# MySQL Can't Connect With Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 computers, one on Mac OS and the second one is on Windows. I have same code written in 
Node.js and MySQL package. I have everything installed on both of the computers. The code works on Windows, But on the Mac it won't connect to MySQL with Node.Js. I can't even create a database.
the error when i try to query something is:
  ***Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:212:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Connection.query (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
    at Handshake. (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/#12/index.js:99:9)
    at Handshake. (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:491:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:125:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/teddykroz/Desktop/Projects/Javascript-Node.js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR',
  fatal: false
}***
But i connect to MySQL before i query something. and when i try to connect it won't print error. and it can't see the database or any tables or even any info.

Comment: The whole key here would be the details of that error message. Can you update the post with these?

Comment: I think the connection was closed by the server. After that, you cannot use the connection variable anymore.